# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while counting key presses

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that automatically counts how many times the numbers on a mobile phone keyboard were pressed, but I am getting a strange error and I don't have a clue why.

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at naloga11.main(naloga11.java:23)
```

code:

```
//naredi tipkovnico

    int max_num = 9;
    String niz = "ta veseli dan ali maticek se zeni xyzq";
    String [] tipkovnica = new String[max_num]; 
    int [] stejvnose = new int[max_num];
    tipkovnica[1] = " ";
    tipkovnica[2] = "abc";
    tipkovnica[3] = "def";
    tipkovnica[4] = "ghi";
    tipkovnica[5] = "jkl";
    tipkovnica[6] = "mno";
    tipkovnica[7] = "pqrs";
    tipkovnica[8] = "tuv";
    tipkovnica[9] = "wxyz";
```

Comment: Array indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: yes but I am never using index 0. I've tried adding it but still gives the same error.

Comment: Then `max_num` needs to be changed to 10 and don't use index 0. Not the best practice, but it will work. Also, why wouldn't you use index 0?

Comment: tipkovnica[0] = " "; ... tipkovnica[8] = "wxyz"; and in this case, array.length == 9 is true. finally, tipkovnica[9] is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException b/c you're trying to use the 10th index in the array when you set the size to 9.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays start counting at 0, so in this case from 0 to 8.

Answer (score 1):

Array's indices start at 0, and your `max_num` has a value of 9, but `tipkovnica[9]` really is index 10, which is why you're getting your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Change your indices to the following:

```
tipkovnica[0] = " ";
tipkovnica[1] = "abc";
tipkovnica[2] = "def";
tipkovnica[3] = "ghi";
tipkovnica[4] = "jkl";
tipkovnica[5] = "mno";
tipkovnica[6] = "pqrs";
tipkovnica[7] = "tuv";
tipkovnica[8] = "wxyz";//9th index, same as your max_num value
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java uses zero-based arrays.** So, if the size is 5 the elements run from index [0-4].
Meaning you would iterate them as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) System.out.println(i);
```

Which (for the new guys) really is equivalent for

```
int i = 0
while (i < array.length)
{
  System.out.println(i)
  i = i + 1;
}
```

But nevertheless, here follow **some ideas that can help you to make your code prettier.**

```
// this is a more pretty way to initialize an array.
// the cute thing, is that you do not even need to specify the capacity.
// however, the array is still fixed size of course.
String[] elements = { "element1", "element2", "element3" };

// this will not compile (and may be confusing)
String[] elements;
elements = { "element1", "element2", "element3" };

// if you do it in 2 lines, then you need to add the class of the array.
String[] elements;
elements = new String[] { "element1", "element2", "element3" };

// but really in 95% of times it is better to use an ArrayList.
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("element1");
list.add("element2");
list.add("element3");

// however, even better is to add generics.
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// if you use Java 7 language level settings or higher
// which probably is the case.
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

The point is, that **it's rarely ever necessary to hardcode the size of an array or collection.**